# Why is the Akka.Serialization.Hyperion serialization package still in beta?

Tags: akka.net

I know that `Akka.Serialization.Hyperion` is scheduled to be the default serialization in Akka.NET 1.4. The beta mark usually means don't use this in production. I was curious what the pitfalls might be around using Hyperion in production at this time.

Comment: AFAIK, Hyperion switch date has been marked on v1.5, not v1.4. It's a necessary step, as current default serializer (JSON.NET) has a number of issues, starting for overall performance, payload size to bugs in very specific scenarios, unresolved for years right now. On the other hand, the feature set of the potential serializer to be considered a default candidate for Akka.NET is very big and beside Hyperion almost no other .NET serializer is able to satisfy it. Re. Hyperion itself - it's an OSS project, which means that work on it progresses in irregular fashion.